# Converting C# to C++

Tags: windows-7, c#, c++, programming

I have tried the [Tangible C# to C++ Converter](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_CPlusPlus_Converter_Details.html) but I'm not happy with it - it generates too many compiler error and even the parts that are compilable may contain issues which make the C++ result different from the C# result.

- OS: Windows 7 SP1 x64 (and higher, if possible)
- budget is ~400 €
- perpetual license, per developer, not machine-bound
- not C++/CLI, since I'd like to avoid the need of the .NET framework
- I don't care much about the C++ version, but the programs are intended to run on Windows 7 SP1 x64 and higher
- I have Visual Studio 2015, but if it works with any free C++ compiler, that'll be fine as well

As a starting point, it should convert this program without problems, which the Tangible solution was not able to do (*remark 2015-12-03: Tangible has provided an updated version of the tool which seems to handle my test correctly now*):

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter an integer number: ");
            var number = Console.ReadLine();
            var i = int.Parse(number);
            Console.WriteLine(i++);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If possible, please mention the size of the project (LOC) that you have converted with it.

Comment: What exact version of C++ are you targeting? There are many, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B Also, what compiler and what version of it are you using?

Comment: Would it be ok, to use more then one tool (it just looks like two conversion steps C# -> C++/CLI, C++/CLI -> Std C++)? And am I correct in the assumption that you have seen a little older SO's post [how to convert C# to C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651249/how-to-convert-c-sharp-to-c)?

Comment: @Florian: multiple steps are ok. Yes, I have see the SO post 1) I don't think Mono answers the question. 2) says it's impossible, 3) says use C# 4) I have not tried Vala yet and 5) is what I have tried

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455456/what-kinds-of-patterns-could-i-enforce-on-the-code-to-make-it-easier-to-translat/3460977#3460977

Comment: So now that Tangible's solution works for your example, can you tell us how big your application to be converted is, and how well the Tangible solutions works on a much larger code base?

Comment: @IraBaxter: I have not tried Tangible again since I was not confident it would work on a larger code base. I have some projects in mind which could benefit from being C++, from a few hundred to ~10000 lines of code.

Comment: Too bad you didn't try Tangible (since you appear to have it) on something larger just to report how well it did.   For any conversion tool, . what is the acceptable conversion error rate?  Zero errors?  At most 5 errors?  At most 5 per thousand lines?   Errors only for C++17 features?

Comment: @IraBaxter: good questions. I'll think about it.

Comment: Is there also some free tools for converting C# to C++?

Comment: @convert That would make a good new question.  Feel free to ask it!