# Free tools for converting C# to C++

Tags: windows, gratis, c++, c#

In some [other thread](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26859/converting-c-to-c#comment99840_26859) here have read, there are some tools able to convert C# to C++. Unfortunatelly it seems they all are comercial and I am not willing to pay money. Is there also some free alternatives for converting C# to C++? To be honest I have no idea about C#, never used it and not going to learn it, but have found some interesting open sorce tools writen in C#. So if there is such free tool for converting C# to C++, can it be used to convert the sorces of that tools?

Comment: Even if a converter could translate from C# to C++, it would be managed C++ which uses the DotNet libraries, is this what you want?

Comment: Not really. C++ code which can´t be compiled with MINGW ist of no use to me.

Comment: I know of https://products.codeporting.com/native  however this tool is not free. I am not sure you will find any free solution

Comment: @Tomislav. Like I said there is an other thread in which some comercial solutions were mentioned. Just out of curiosity, is that trial version just limited by time or functionality? Does that tool produce real C++ code, or just some managed trash?

Comment: There are open source implementations of C#, e.g. https://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: What is the size (in thousands of C# source lines) of the open source software you want to convert? Consider naming an example of open source C# software you are interested in!

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Have no idea how many lines of code that software has, as soon, I saw it is writen in C#, it was of no interest for me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this is even possible, C# is relying on the DotNet libraries and on the garbage collector, so a converter had to convert the whole DotNet environment and reimplement features of the language.

(I'm assuming that you don't mean to use managed C++, which requires the DotNet environment as well.)

Comment: Read here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26859/converting-c-to-c?noredirect=1#comment99840_26859 about such tool and was wonderin if there is a similar freeware tool. Somebody there tolld me to ask it as separate question, which like I see now was posibly not such good idea. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: I'm impressed that somebody even tried to write such a converter, but apart from the most basic examples I would never trust this code, the concepts (especially for freeing memory) are too far away. I wonder how restricted one is in using the DotNet framework libraries, it seems impossible that they found an equivalent for a significant part of all available classes.

Comment: As I commented on another similar answer: while C# has a garbage collector, it does not *need* one. The resources could be freed right away. Whether or not an object is garbage collected in 3 minutes or right after the scope does not really matter.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - The problem is see is a different one, because there _is_ a garbage collector, developers write different code. Returning a new created list inside a function is common, and nobody cares whether the list owns its items or if it holds references only. Switching from an unmanaged language to a language with garbage collector is easy, the opposite is very tricky, a lot of developers are not used to it anymore.

Comment: You can return a `vector`, can't you? Modern C++ much more similar to C# than I thought. I always made my way around C++, but since I coded ~20 challenges on CodeWars, I must admit that C++ may finally be a language which I consider coding in.

Comment: @martinstoeckli So C# has garbage collector, similar to Java?

Comment: @convert - Yes, the garbage collector belongs to the .Net environment, so all .Net languages are using it.

Answer (score 1):

You may check [C# to C++ translator](https://products.codeporting.com/translator/csharp-to-cpp/release). It has .Net BCL implementation for C++. The converter is available [here](https://products.codeporting.app/convert/csharp-to-cpp-project/) or [here](https://products.codeporting.app/convert/csharp-to-cpp/) but it has limitations. You may write to developers, they are open for requests.

The converter is used on production to convert solutions up to 1M lines of code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile and use open source C# software, you could use [mono](https://www.mono-project.com/).

It is some open source implementation of C# (and its CLR runtime) - documented to run on Linux, Windows, MacOSX.

Converting C# to [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) requires a lot of work. You need to be expert in both C# and C++ (so take a week of work reading books about both of them). Be aware of the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html) (it has no equivalent in C#). I tend to think that fully automatic conversion (to *readable* and human-editable C++ code) is in practice impossible (e.g. because of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)).

With [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), you probably could call C++ libraries from C# code (assuming an open source mindset).

BTW, backtracing is possible in C++ on Linux with Ian Lance Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace), that the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project and the  [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler uses. You would compile your C++ code with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -O -fPIC` and use [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) on Linux. Read the [C++ dlopen minihowto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/).

Comment: But since I would like to convert from C# to C++ and not from C++ to C# not have much to vory about rule of five, even not about rule of three.

Comment: You probably do need the *generated* C++ code to follow the rule of five.

Comment: Why? I am never using that move stuf. Also that rules make sence only when memory is alocated dynamically.

Comment: Also if using only smart pointers instead of that old C style ones, can just ignore that rules.